# How to install font-awesome to node_modules

Tags: node.js, angular, font-awesome

I recently installed font-awesome for an angular project, but ran into some issues with where it was saved. When I use:

`npm install font-awesome`

it adds a node_modules folder to the root of my project. This would be fine, but I already have a node_modules folder in the project. Then I tried using:

`npm install font-awesome -p ./path/to/node_modules`

It says that there is no package.json file, but I can see that there is one. Am I doing this wrong? If so, how can I specify that I want the font-awesome installation in the existing node_modules folder?

Comment: if you already have font-awesome in your package.json and you get your code on a new folder/pc, you just need to run `npm install` to reinstall all packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are running `npm install font-awesome` in the root directory where package.json and node_modules (if existing) resides.

Answer (score 0):

In command prompt go to folder where package.json is and run the command below :-

```
npm i font-awesome --save
```